# Page appearing differently on different machines with same browser (chrome)

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, web, wordpress-theming

I have purchased a Wordpress theme ([Core](http://themes.themegoods.com/?theme=Core)) for a client's website. The theme works perfectly fine on my machine and any machine I have access to. Here is a screenshot of what it looks like: [image: Correct one].

Now, when the same page is opened on client's machine (in another country), it opens the page like this: [image: Wrong one]

I have tried contacting theme support but got no help. I have also tried everything I could to resolve it; deleting cache, removing history, and similar stuff is already done and it does not help either. CSS Reset is also part of the CSS code provided by theme. Can anyone give me any idea of what could be going wrong here? Client is trying on Chrome too (updating Chrome does not help either).

Also, client has reported that issue is appearing on his friend's machines. But definitely nothing like this happening at my end.

Site available at: http://goldentouchproductions.com.au/

Comment: Did the client use zoom?

Comment: The shots are apparently at the same zoom level, the client one is at higher resolution, that's why it seems zoomed out in the reduced view above.

Comment: I am not sure but I have sent someone I know in that country to meet client even and check his machine and he said he is using it normally. So, I don't think zoom should be involved. Also, I tried using zoom on my machine and nothing is happening to images at my end. As per theme, they are setup according to %age of screen size.

Comment: Btw, site is available at: http://goldentouchproductions.com.au/

Comment: Maybe ask the client to try another browser and see if it's the same there too.

Comment: Yes, I tried. he didn't want to try another browser. He said I use Chrome and it should appear fine on Chrome :(

Comment: @Ianzz... Image size gets adjusted as per the size of the browser window. so, bigger the screen, bigger the image, right? but on an overall, it should always appear in that area as per my understanding.

Comment: Yes, he did clear cache.

Comment: Anyone commenting here getting the images in small size too?

Comment: No, it appears fine for me in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE 7/8. Although in IE the image gallery is painfully slow making it virtually unusable.

Comment: @BillyMoat ... thanks for the feedback. Yes, the gallery is actually really slow.

Comment: I figured out the issue. Basically, user had a Chrome plugin installed for uTorrent on Chrome and it was messing up the images on page. I do not know why but it was obviously doing something (probably because of extra search bar it was showing).

I disabled the plugin and everything appeared fine and as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. Basically, user had a Chrome plugin installed for uTorrent on Chrome and it was messing up the images on page. I do not know why but it was obviously doing something (probably because of extra search bar it was showing).

I disabled the plugin and everything appeared fine and as expected.